# Saxon CS: transform.doTransform cannot find out file from first transformation on windows machine but can on mac

Tags: saxon

I am creating an azure function application to validate xml files using a zip folder of schematron files.
I have run into a compatibility issue with how the URI's for the files are being created between mac and windows.
The files are downloaded from a zip on azure blob storage and then extracted to the functions local storage.

When the a colleague runs the transform method of the saxon cs api on a windows machine the method is able to run the first transformation and produce the stage 1.out file, however on the second transformation the transform method throws an exception stating that it cannot find the file even though it is present on the temp directory.

On mac the URI is /var/folders/6_/3x594vpn6z1fjclc0vx4v89m0000gn/T and on windows it is trying to find it at file:///C:/Users/44741/AppData/Local/Temp/ but the library is unable to find the file on the windows machine even if it is moved out of temp storage.

Unable to retrieve URI file:///C:/Users/44741/Desktop/files/stage1.out

The file is present at this location but for some reason the library cannot pick it up on the windows machine but it works fine on my mac. I am using Path.Combine to build the URI.

Has anyone else ran into this issue before?
The code being used for the transformations is below.

````
    {
        try
        {
            var transform = new Transform();
            transform.doTransform(GetTransformArguments(arguments[Constants.InStage1File],
                arguments[Constants.SourceDir] + "/" + schematronFile, arguments[Constants.Stage1Out]));
            transform.doTransform(GetTransformArguments(arguments[Constants.InStage2File], arguments[Constants.Stage1Out],
                arguments[Constants.Stage2Out]));
            transform.doTransform(GetFinalTransformArguments(arguments[Constants.InStage3File], arguments[Constants.Stage2Out],
                arguments[Constants.Stage3Out]));
            Log.Information("Stage 3 out file written to : " + arguments[Constants.Stage3Out]);;
            return true;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Log.Warning("Cannot find files" + ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static string[] GetTransformArguments(string xslFile, string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            "-xsl:" + xslFile,
            "-s:" + inputFile,
            "-o:" + outputFile
        };
    }

    private static string[] GetFinalTransformArguments(string xslFile, string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            "-xsl:" + xslFile,
            "-s:" + inputFile,
            "-o:" + outputFile,
            "allow-foreign=true",
            "generate-fired-rule=true"
        };
    }```
````

Comment: Add a stack trace if you have one. Given that you write C# code to run XSLT, have you considered to use Saxon's .NET API (i.e. Xslt30Transformer) from your code instead of relying on calling the command line tool API?

Comment: Of course, if you can use the s9api, the next question on how to use it exactly is whether you need the intermediary results or could just chain the transforms to have the final output as a file?

Comment: As for existing knowledge about the problem, I think an issue got reported (here and/or at the Saxonica support site) that even with C# using s9api, on Windows, if you try to run a second transformation on the output file of the first you will find that the file was not closed properly by Saxon and therefore the second transformation can't open it for reading as the earlier write access that should have been closed blocks any access. But as a workaround, in SaxonCS, currently, you can set up your own handler ensuring that the file stream is closed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72473156/252228

Comment: Bug issue is https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5552, perhaps Michael/Saxonica can check whether the patch there also fixes chaining two SaxonCS `doTransform` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming the intermediary results are not needed as files but you just want the result (I assume that is the Schematron schema compiled to XSLT) you could try to run XSLT 3.0 using the API of SaxonCS (`using Saxon.Api`) by compiling and chaining your three stylesheets with e.g.

```
using Saxon.Api;

string isoSchematronDir = @"C:\SomePath\SomeDir\iso-schematron-xslt2";

string[] isoSchematronXslts = { "iso_dsdl_include.xsl", "iso_abstract_expand.xsl", "iso_svrl_for_xslt2.xsl" };

Processor processor = new(true);

var xsltCompiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();

var baseUri = new Uri(Path.Combine(isoSchematronDir, isoSchematronXslts[2]));

xsltCompiler.BaseUri = baseUri;

var isoSchematronStages = isoSchematronXslts.Select(xslt => xsltCompiler.Compile(new Uri(baseUri, xslt)).Load30()).ToList();

isoSchematronStages[2].SetStylesheetParameters(new Dictionary<QName, XdmValue>() { { new QName("allow-foreign"), new XdmAtomicValue(true) } });


using (var schematronIs = File.OpenRead("price.sch"))
{
using (var compiledOs = File.OpenWrite("price.sch.xsl"))

{
    isoSchematronStages[0].ApplyTemplates(
        schematronIs, 
        isoSchematronStages[1].AsDocumentDestination(
            isoSchematronStages[2].AsDocumentDestination(processor.NewSerializer(compiledOs)
        )
    );
}
}
```

If you only need the compiled Schematron to apply it further to validate an XML instance document against that Schematron you could even store the Schematron as an XdmDestination whose XdmNode you feed to XsltCompiler e.g.

```
using Saxon.Api;

string isoSchematronDir = @"C:\SomePath\SomeDir\iso-schematron-xslt2";

string[] isoSchematronXslts = { "iso_dsdl_include.xsl", "iso_abstract_expand.xsl", "iso_svrl_for_xslt2.xsl" };

Processor processor = new(true);

var xsltCompiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();

var baseUri = new Uri(Path.Combine(isoSchematronDir, isoSchematronXslts[2]));

xsltCompiler.BaseUri = baseUri;

var isoSchematronStages = isoSchematronXslts.Select(xslt => xsltCompiler.Compile(new Uri(baseUri, xslt)).Load30()).ToList();

isoSchematronStages[2].SetStylesheetParameters(new Dictionary<QName, XdmValue>() { { new QName("allow-foreign"), new XdmAtomicValue(true) } });

var compiledSchematronXslt = new XdmDestination();

using (var schematronIs = File.OpenRead("price.sch"))
{
    isoSchematronStages[0].ApplyTemplates(
        schematronIs, 
        isoSchematronStages[1].AsDocumentDestination(
            isoSchematronStages[2].AsDocumentDestination(compiledSchematronXslt)
        )
    );
}

var schematronValidator = xsltCompiler.Compile(compiledSchematronXslt.XdmNode).Load30();

using (var sampleIs = File.OpenRead("books.xml"))
{
    schematronValidator.ApplyTemplates(sampleIs, processor.NewSerializer(Console.Out));
}
```

The last example writes the XSLT/Schematron validation SVRL output to the console but could of course also write it to a file.